# How to create 64-bit CUDA applications? (Win7 x64, CUDA 4, VS 2010 Express)

Tags: cuda

I'm mostly set up for CUDA development. I've installed the developer drivers, CUDA 4.0 toolkit, and the 4.0 SDK, as well as the bugfix. I'm running Windows 7 x64, and am using Visual C++ 2010 Express. For 32-bit applications, I perform the following steps and my CUDA applications work properly.

- Create new empty project
- make sure Platform Toolset is set to v100 (normally the default)
- check the CUDA 4.0 Build Customization for the project
- set the item type of my .cu file to CUDA C/C++
- add 'cudart.lib' to Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

I can also run non-CUDA 64-bit applications. Visual C++ 2010 Express does not come with 64-bit dependencies automatically, so I had to install the Windows 7.1 SDK w/ .NET Framework 4.0. Then I simply set the Platform Toolset for the VC++ project to Windows7.1SDK, change the Active solution platform to x64, and I'm good to go.

However, I can't seem to do both at the same time - I can't create a 64-bit CUDA application. If I change the Platform Toolset of a CUDA application to Windows7.1SDK, whether the Active solution platform is x64 or Win32, I get the compile error that nvcc.exe exited with code -1. And if I leave the Platform Toolset set to v100 and change the Active solution platform to x64, I get the compile error "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'. The only combination that works is v100 and Win32, and obviously that prevents me from running a 64-bit application.

Is there a procedure for enabling this functionality that I just haven't been able to find online? Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you installed the 64-bit CUDA Toolkit and 64-bit CUDA SDK? If so, are you able to build and run the SDK samples for x64?

Comment: I've definitely installed the 64-bit versions of both the Toolkit and the SDK. I have not tried to run the samples, I've been running my own code - but I will try the samples.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in express edition , ( does not support plugins )  unless you want to  setup nvcc  manually , and use notepad to write cu  files,  I very much prefer the VS integration .

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the host compiler properties for the .cu files are set to 64-bit.
Right-click the "Code.cu" file and click 'Properties'.
Expand the "CUDA C/C++" item and select "Common".
Change "Target Machine Platform" to 64-bit.